# Duplicate ticket number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find if there are any duplicate ticket number in my table.
my code below is displaying the first ticket number from classes table which is 1039, I want to diplay if there is a duplicate.  1039 is NOT a duplicate.  what is my problem?

```
$query = "SELECT ticket, COUNT(ticket) AS NumOccurrences FROM classes GROUP BY ticket HAVING (COUNT(ticket) > 1)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{
$ticket = $row['ticket'];
}

if($result)
{
echo $ticket. "<br/>";
echo "there are " . mysql_num_rows($result) . " tickets ";
}

else
{
echo "no duplicate ";
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise you're counting all tickets.

```
SELECT ticket, COUNT(*) c FROM classes GROUP BY ticket HAVING (c > 1)
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `HAVING NumOccurrences > 1` rather than repeating `COUNT(ticket)`. Hopefully mysql can optimize the common subexpression, but why depend on it? I think this is clearer AND likely to be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT ticket, COUNT(ticket) as `count` FROM classes GROUP BY ticket WHERE `count` > 1
```